# Stratified Sampling vs. Hand picking a "random sample", and using Chi-Squared as justification. Dichotomous outcome methods question

Tags: sampling, stratification

Suppose I would like to evaluate "the proportion of potato farms in Idaho that use pesticides". (dichotomous yes/no outcome variable). Now let's assume I know the exact number of potato farms in Idaho, and the county that each is in. Further, perhaps I have reason to believe that county might be a predictor of whether or not a given farm uses pesticides.

I am going to distribute a yes/no survey to a sample of Idaho potato farms to ask whether or not they use pesticides. In my initial power analysis, I find that I should survey at least 500 farms to be within my desired confidence interval +/- a comfortable margin of error (I used a margin of error equation for binary data with a finite population correction factor)

Now assume that we randomly select 500 farms for survey. But then, my supervisor says "I want to survey at least 10 farms per county, because we want to be sure that all counties are represented and we're going to report out to each of them, so tweak the selection to make sure at least 10 farms per county are included".

Now my instinct says, here lies a problem. We're violating an assumption of the "Simple Random Sample" (each farm in Idaho should have had an equal chance to be selected for survey if our ultimate research question is to make an inference of Idaho potato farms as a whole), thus invalidating our results. So instead, I suggest we use stratified sampling, and evaluate each county individually to figure out the sample size required to make an inference about each (using the same confidence interval and margin of error as before, but now at the county level). The problem is, this math tells me we'd need to send WAY more surveys, and we don't have the resources to do so. Some counties would require essentially every farm to be surveyed.

My supervisor says "stick to the (altered) draw of 500 farms. I ran a series of chi-squared tests on some key characteristics, and found that our sample (the new one where we made sure at least 10 farms per county were included) does not differ from the population of Idaho potato farms as a whole, thus our methods are sound". He says we can add a caveat that we didn't tweak our selection to have confidence with in-county results, but just to be sure we had an equitable spread across the state.

How do I explain that this isn't sound, and what methods should I suggest? Any links to papers, formulas etc. would be super helpful. I changed the subject manner but I'm actually dealing with this, but don't have the expertise to explain why this is wrong, just enough to know that it is and you can't just whip up a chi-squared tests and say it's all good.

Comment: See this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457769/sample-stratification-by-dependent-variable-in-linear-regression-analysis/457772#457772

Comment: Some sort of stratified sampling seems appropriate. Choose farms within counties at random.  Might the sizes of farms help explain whether pesticides are used? Plan your design and how you will analyze it in advance of taking data; you have a good start on that with your power and sample size computation.